# Add a tree folder category on the left sidebar of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to add a tree folder category on the left sidebar of Windows 10?
I don’t want to add it to Quick access, the tree structure cannot `be expanded`

I expected like OneDrive folder, you can expand the bottom folder on the left
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Access contents are shortcuts (another view) to folders in This PC.

It is not advisable (in my view) to add folders there (I have seen additions go to the wrong place).

Add whatever folders you wish under This PC.

See the screen shot to help you.

[image]